# Ruby - Why does Dir.foreach pass `.` and `..` as the first two parameters?

Tags: ruby, foreach

In an empty directory, the following code

```
Dir.foreach("./") do |file|
  puts file
end
```

returns

```
.
..
```

In my understanding `.` refers to the working directory and `..` refers to the parent directory; why does `foreach` seem to treat them as files within the working directory?

Comment: Because they are files in the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they *are* files within the working directory.  The `.` and `..` directories are not magical; they appear the same way any subdirectory does, as entries in the directory.  Every directory on a UNIX-type file system has actual directory entries named `.` and `..`.  So if you don't want to include them when processing a directory, you need to exclude them yourself.